# Index out of range after removing item from list

Tags: python

I am making a wordle word finder by taking all possible wordle answers and removing those who don't fit the word criteria. Currently, I am going through the list of the words and removing those that do not have all user-specified letters. However, when running the program with both a test set and the real set, I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` on the `if` statement in the body of the second `for` loop.

My code:

```
data = text_file.read()
text_file.close()
def convert(string):
    return list(string.split(" "))
wordle = convert(data)

data = input("Enter known letters:\n")
in_word = convert(data)



for i in range(len(wordle)):


    for x in range(len(in_word)):
        if in_word[x] not in wordle[i]:
            wordle.remove(wordle[i])
            break
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that `for x in range(len(in_word))` only ever retrieves a character (ie. `x` is not really used) so you can just say `for character in in_word`. I suspect your error, though, might have to do with you mutating while iterating. You should just apply a filter (because the length of `wordle` changes whenever you remove) so you can just say `wordle = [word for word in wordle if all(character in word for character in in_word)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *never* recommended to edit an object while you're iterating over it. What is happening is that you're shortening your list while keeping the for loop the same (so at the end your list could be 3 elements long but your for loop will still count to the original length of 5 - or whatever). I would keep a separate list and just put a condition in your if statement:

```
skip_list = []
for i in range(len(wordle)):
    for x in range(len(in_word)):
        if in_word[x] not in wordle[i]:
            skip_list.append(wordle[i])
            break
wordle = [i for i in wordle if i not in skip_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just using a conditional to evaluate if the value is present in `wordle` to reassign on *list*

```
wordle = [x if x in wordle for x in in_word]
```